# How to set OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext as parent of WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-ws, apache-karaf, spring-dm

In my Camel (2.14.0) application I use Spring Web Services to trigger Camel routes. The artifact is built as an OSGi bundle and deployed in Karaf (3.0.2).

For the first version I configured spring-ws to use the JVM internal web server through the `org.springframework.remoting.support.SimpleHttpServerFactoryBean` to expose the web service. This works just fine. But is not very OSGi-ish. So instead I would like to publish the `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet` as a service to the [Karaf whiteboard extender](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/ops4j/Pax+Web+Extender+-+Whiteboard) like so:

```
<bean id="pas-ws-patient-servlet" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet">
    <property name="contextConfigLocation" value="/endpoint-mapping.xml" /> 
</bean>

<osgi:service ref="pas-ws-patient-servlet" interface="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/${pas.ws.patient.contextroot}" />
    </service-properties>
</osgi:service>
```

Which works like a charm for "regular" servlets. But the `MessageDispatcherServlet` wants to build its own `WebApplicationContext` and expects to find a bean of type `org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointMapping` in that context. Camel provides an implementation of `EndpointMapping` that has to be used with its spring-ws component.

The problem I am facing is that the same instance of the endpoint mapping bean must be shared between the `OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext` that creates the Camel context and the application context created by the `MessageDispatcherServlet`. Which would be the case if my `OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext` was the parent of the `WebApplicationContext`. Though how to set the parent context of the `WebApplicationContext` to the "current" context from which I am publishing the servlet as a service eludes me.

Instantiating a `WebApplicationContext` from within the `OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext` to pass it to the MessageDispatcherServlet gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve ServletContextResource without ServletContext
```

Unfortunately the `WebServiceMessageReceiver` (which encapsulates the `EndpointMapping`) of the `MessageDispatcherServlet` is a private member. So I cannot set the mapping bean either in a straight forward way.

Is there a way to create the context hierarchy? Or can a bean instance be shared across contexts in another way?

Comment: any reason for not using blueprint to configure this?

Comment: @AchimNierbeck Not anymore, I think. I am using spring-dm because setting up spring-ws with the JDK webserver and/or with endpoint interceptors requires the use of the [spring-ws](http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services) namespace, which is [not supported](http://qnalist.com/questions/5374905/bundle-using-camel-spring-ws-failes-to-deploy-in-karaf) by blueprint. How is deploying through blueprint going to solve the bean-visibility problem though? The spring-ws servlet insists on creating its own application context. Is there an OSGi/blueprint version of the servlet available?

Comment: well, camel is optimized to run with blueprint in osgi environments, no need to use spring there. regarding webservices, use cxf directly it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually straight forward and documented in the JavaDoc of `FrameworkServlet`, which the `MessageDispatcherServlet` extends:

One can set an `ApplicationContextInitializer` on the MessageDispatcherServlet. Use the context initializer to set the current application context as the parent of the servlet's application context. For this you have to also implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface to get a hold of the current context (`OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext` in this case). Then register the servlet as a service:

```
<!-- This bean sets our current context as the parent context of the XmlWebApplicationContext 
    that the MessageDispatcherServlet insists on creating. -->
<bean id="springWsContextInitializer" class="x.x.x.SpringWsContextInitializer" />

<bean id="spring-ws-servlet" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet">
    <!-- We inherit all beans from the current context, so no need to specify a separate context file. -->
    <property name="contextConfigLocation" value="" />
    <property name="ContextInitializers" ref="springWsContextInitializer" />
</bean>

<osgi:service ref="spring-ws-servlet" interface="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/${servlet.contextroot}" />
        <entry key="servlet-name" value="spring-ws-servlet" />
    </service-properties>
</osgi:service>
```

The context initializer class:

```
public class SpringWsContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<XmlWebApplicationContext>, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        applicationContext.setParent(this.applicationContext);
    }
}
```

To get the same thing to work using **blueprint** instead of spring-dw I had to change the SpringWsContextInitializer to like so:

```
public class SpringWsContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private final EndpointMapping endpointMapping;

    public SpringWsContextInitializer(final EndpointMapping endpointMapping) {
        this.endpointMapping = endpointMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        StaticApplicationContext parentContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
        parentContext.refresh();
        parentContext.getDefaultListableBeanFactory().registerSingleton("endpointMapping", this.endpointMapping);
        applicationContext.setParent(parentContext);
    }
}
```

It should be possible to publish the endpoint mapping bean as an OSGi service and then reference the service bean in a context file for the servlet, but the OSGi namespace handler for the OSGi namespace needed on the spring context file could not be resolved.